# Skip arguments in C

Tags: c

I wrote a C program which has `sum`, `sub`, `mul` and `div` commands when the input is given in the following formats:

> sum 2 3
>   5
>
> sub 4 3
>   1
>
> ...

I'm able to complete every operation. But, in the end, when I need to exit the program, I should give only a `bye` command as input and the program should stop its execution. But, the program is exiting only if I give 2 numbers along with `bye`. How do I exit the program only with `bye` by itself?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int op1,op2;                              
    char opera[3];                          
    do
    {
        printf("please enter input(operator operand1 operand2)"); 

        if ((opera[3]>='a' && opera[3]<='z')|| (opera[3]>='A' && opera[3]<='Z'))  
        {
            printf("The operands are not valid", opera[3]);
        }
        scanf("%s %d %d",opera,&op1,&op2); 

        if (strcmp(opera, "bye") == 0)
        {
            printf("Bye");
            exit(0);
        }

        if (strcmp(opera, "sum") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d",op1+op2);
        }

        else if (strcmp(opera, "sub") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d",op1-op2);
        }

        else if (strcmp(opera, "mul") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d",op1*op2);
        }

        else if (strcmp(opera, "div") == 0)
        {
            if (op2 == 0)
            {
                printf("The expression is invalid");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d",op1/op2);
            }
        }
    }
    while (opera != getchar());
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `char opera[3];` --> `char opera[4];` and Split `"%s %d %d"` to `"%3s"` and `"%d %d"`.

Comment: `if ((opera[3]>='a' && opera[3]<='z')|| (opera[3]>='A' && opera[3]<='Z'))  
        {
            printf("The operands are not valid", opera[3]);
        }` --> `else { printf("The operands are not valid\n"); }` and move to after last else-if-block.

Answer (score 1):

You have a buffer overflow in `opera[]`, and you are not reading arguments correctly.  Try something more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    int op1, op2;
    char opera[4];

    do
    {
        printf("please enter input (operator operand1 operand2): ");

        if (scanf("%3s", opera) != 1)
            continue;

        if (strcmp(opera, "bye") == 0)
        {
            printf("Bye");
            exit(0);
            return;
        }

        if (scanf("%d %d", &op1, &op2) != 2)
        {
            printf("The operands are not valid\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (strcmp(opera, "sum") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", op1+op2);
        }

        else if (strcmp(opera, "sub") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", op1-op2);
        }

        else if (strcmp(opera, "mul") == 0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", op1 * op2);
        }

        else if (strcmp(opera, "div") == 0)
        {
            if (op2 == 0)
            {
                printf("The expression is invalid\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d\n", op1 / op2);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            printf("The operator is invalid\n");
        }
    }
    while (1);

    getch();
}
```